# OpenCMS and CVS

Tags: eclipse, version-control, cvs, opencms

How does one integrate working with CVS and OpenCMS, specifically looking at maintaining properties and metadata?

I have OpenCMS set up on my local machine for development, as well as Eclipse connected to CVS.  I can synch files between OpenCMS and Eclipse and check them into CVS, that works fine - except I don't know of any way to version control the properties and other metadata.

Answer (score 0):

One question: how do you sync the OpenCms files? Are you talking about the VFS (virtual file system = mysql data files)? Because in OpenCms, all content files reside in the VFS, not on the real file system (RFS).

You are talking about the content files of your OpenCms site, right? Not the OpenCms core source files that you're using to recompile the OpenCms core jar, I assume.

One idea is to map a drive to the VFS using WebDAV, but I found it's not very stable and reliable. With that, you would usually also get the properties in a separate folder.

Comment: Yes, currently we're syncing the OpenCMS files to the RFS and then checking them in.  And yes, just the files for our site and module (no core OpenCMS source files).  We looked at WebDAV but we were skeptical of it since it's so out of date.

Comment: It's been a while when I last tried to use WebDAV in OpenCms, but if I remember correctly, there were usually additional folders that were holding the meta data, usually in the same directory level as the file itself, not? Maybe I'm wrong. However, I think WebDAV is the only way to do it.

Comment: This might also be a helpful link - it's OpenCms the mailing list archive: http://old.nabble.com/forum/Search.jtp?forum=654&local=y&query=opencms+svn (maybe the Maven plugin mentioned there is an option)

Answer (score 0):

IF you use maven, you can use the `org.synyx:maven-opencms` plugin. Using it, you develop your VFS content of your module, including properties, in your IDE instead of directly in OpenCms. The plugin enables you to import it into OpenCms with a maven goal. If you don't develop inside the VFs, you can put your stuff into CVS trivially.

The maven plugin is based on some ant task, so you can use ant, too if you don't like maven. The task can be downloaded from http://www.eurelis.com/fr/downloads/opencms-ant-task/